# Should a SpyderPro be used to calibrate an HDR monitor in Windows?

Tags: display, color-profiles, calibration

I have calibrated my non-HDR monitors many times with my Spyder calibrator, but I just got an HDR monitor for the first time. I use my monitor in both HDR and non-HDR modes, depending on the scenario.

1. **Should I use my Spyder to calibrate this monitor in non-HDR mode?**
2. **Does calibration done in non-HDR mode affect HDR mode?**

I just generally don't understand how color profiles work between non-HDR and HDR modes when Windows detects the monitor as one device. Does it use different .icm profiles for the two modes?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I don't want the downvotes;) HDR is a waste of space. It's a consumer 'fake' guesswork to make you think your monitor is 'better'. It has zero value if you want to actually view a calibrated, accurate image. If you have any 'smart' features on your screen to 'aid' your viewing, switch them all off before calibration & leave them off. If you switch on HDR you wasted your money on the Spyder. (If sufficient people actually upvote this comment I shall flesh it out as a proper answer.)

Comment: @Tetsujin I use SDR for photo/video work, but HDR is nice for gaming.

Comment: Then set it up & calibrate with literally every 'smart' structure switched off. Hopefully it has more than one memory location so you don't have to recalibrate every time you switch over.